# Cladding color of a two tone Lexus ES 300

Tags: paint, lexus

My ES300, like most models has a two tone paint job. After doing some research on Lexus paint codes, I found that the driver side door has a label specifying the exact color - for the paint on the top part of the car which is on the bonnet, trunk etc.

The code is **4M7/LF61** and online lookup states the color is [Oyster Pearl](http://workshop-manuals.com/lexus/es_300/v6-3.0l_(1mz-fe)/body_and_frame/paint_striping_and_decals/paint/system_information/technical_service_bulletins/technical_service_bulletins_for_paint/pa001-97/mar/97/paint_refinish_formula_codes/names/applications/), although in some cases it is also called as [Flaxen Pearl](https://fyralip.com/find_your_paintcode/lexus) (and the swatch looks quite different).

The second color, used for the lower half of the doors and the bumpers; is something I haven't been able to look up. [This pdf](https://www.ih8mud.com/tech/tsb/LexusLX450/lpa00296.pdf) inspired me to do similar searches and find that [4M7 goes with UCAA2](http://workshop-manuals.com/lexus/es_300/v6-3.0l_(1mz-fe)/body_and_frame/paint_striping_and_decals/paint/system_information/technical_service_bulletins/technical_service_bulletins_for_paint/pa003-96/dec/96/paint_codes/page_4675/) - for the GS300.

Is there any source to find out cladding color used with **4M7** for the **ES** 300 (1997)?

Answer (score 1):

Cladding color of a two tone Lexus ES 300

I have a 1998 Lexus ES300 with two tone cladding. The drivers side door label indicates 4MV / LF61. Unless my eyesight has failed me not sure why most references on the internet use 4M7 to identify the top portion of the cladding color pair. It is grayish / silverish so Oyster Pearl sounds about right. I hope this helps you.